# Eager Loading multiple child collections in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework but have experience with NHibernate. I'm trying to load an object that has multiple child collections, and I'm trying to eagerly load both child collections.

I assume I can do something like:

```
return DataContext.Users.Include("ChildCollection1").Include("ChildCollection2")
```

but is there a way to split that into two queries to increase performance like I could in NHibernate by using Future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is the FutureQueries functionality in the EntityFramework.Extended library: https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Future-Queries.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about NH.But do you mean the explicit loading in EF?

```
Context.Entry(aUser).Collection(u => u.ChildCollectionX).Load();
```

Comment: You can load one property when the entity first got loaded with the include method,and then load some other unloaded properties in the explicit way at any time you like,is that not what you need?

Comment: Downside is that this has to be called per-entity, so it is not efficient if you have many entities that you need child collections for.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/27/nhibernate-futures.aspx), futures in NHibernate are a way to defer the execution of queries to a later moment in order to execute queries in batch. It uses NHibernate's [MultiQuery feature](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/eager-loading-aggregate-with-many-child-collections.aspx).

Entity Framework has nothing that looks like this. So far, `Include` is the only option to load child collections in one shot.

The [road map](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap), although not very detailed, does not show any plans in this direction.

Answer (score -1):

I could not make it work with lambdas but it works with the string path...

```
        using (var db = new CMWebTestContext())
        {
           var q = db.WebTestResults.Include("TestCollection.TransactionCollection.PageCollection");
           var r = q.ToList();
           return r;
        }
```